# Cannot connect to internet on wired connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, ethernet

I just built a computer and freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a new hdd but cannot connect to the internet when plugging in an ethernet cable. My computer doesn't have a wireless adapter so wireless isn't an option. I've tried going to "Edit connections" and adding a new Ethernet connection via the IPv4 Settings but haven't had any luck.

After running `ping -c3 192.168.2.1`(my router's address) I get:

```
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/0.033/0.037/0.007 ms
```

I've read somewhere that I need to specify DNS server address such as 8.8.8.8 in different places but it hasn't worked for me.

Can anyone suggest what I should try next?

Answer (score 0):

To see if your DNS configuration is fine, ry to type:

```
dig canonical.com
```

If you don't have a reply (giving canonical name servers addresses), check your configuration:

To enter (and verify) your network settings, go to the system settings/Network panel. Select the wired interface and click the Options button.

Then in the IPv4 tab you should be able to type a DNS server address, at least if your interface is not configured with DHCP. If so, try to set up an IP address manually. Maybe your router don't dispatch DNS server address.

HTH